# layout preview not visible in android studio 1.2

Tags: android

I have recently installed android studio on my windows 7 professional.
when I opened it..the layout preview..that is the default device which appears on the right in preview tab is not visible rather displaying the message:

"Rendering problems
This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of Android Studio. Please update Android Studio".
What should I do.?

Comment: This is common and never works for me. Post your XML so we can see what views are not working.

Comment: I have not changed the XML..it is default till now..my query is that the device that appears for the layout..usually Nexus4 by default is not visible on my screen.

Answer (score 0):

On the top right corner on your design surface, you have dropdown to choose version (with android launcher icon). I suspect it is currently set to API 22 (android M). You can change the API level and see what is compatible with your android studio version.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest updating Android Studio like it is telling you. Its under Help>Check For Update...  If it says you already have the latest update then click on the blue Updates  Link and it will pop a menu up for you to change your update settings. I keep Android Studio updating from the Stable Channel or the Dev channel. The safest is the stable channel. I think the stable version at this time is 1.2.2. The 1.2.2 build will not render with M Preview.

Comment: Cool i am glad it worked. Dont forget to mark your question resolved. Happy coding.